# Adding 2D versions of real cars in a game can be a legal issue?

Tags: 2d, game-design, racing

I've been thinking in doing a car game, but i wanted to add "real" cars into the game. Are 2D renditions of the cars with sprites/vector 2d graphics fine?

Comment: Apply the same logic as your previous question: does someone own that real-world thing? Might that owner want to control how their property is represented, or receive compensation when their property is used as a feature in someone else's product? Might that owner decide to send you a cease & desist notice or pursue legal action against you if you try to use their stuff without their permission? What's stopping them from doing so?

Comment: Check the [Pole Position II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_Position_II#Re-releases) article on Wikipedia. On "Re-releases" section: "Pole Position II has been re-released as part of various Namco Museum compilations, but the two active permanent circuits were removed (because of licensing issues with both Fuji and Suzuka)." If Namco had to negotiate licenses I asume we have too.

Comment: Please do not edit questions to completely change their topic. If you're unable to infer the answer to this from the resources that have been provided to you, you should post it as a new question, rather than editing a closed question into something else entirely.